# Web service requests multiple times before get the response in HTTP

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, ipad, http

The *body* variable contains more that 100 values with images. For ex. here are some of them.

```
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"shot_count\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:stringImagePathCount] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];
```

When the HTTP request goes it will come with the Response. But the problem here is when request processing in server, if it don't get the response then it requests again. We will get the response after processing the request completes. But the same copy of the data POSTing more than two times in server. How can we solve this problem?

```
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSArray *books=[returnString JSONValue];
    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request   delegate:self];
    if( theConnection )
    {
        receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
        NSLog(@"receivedData %@",receivedData);

    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
    }
```

Thanks in advance.